# Tkinter: parent widgets and using Toplayer()

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm new to Tkinter and don't understand how to use Toplayer. Can someone please help me and explain what I need to add to my code to stop this AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'tk.

And here are the key bits of the code

```
def welcome_screen():
    global welcome_screen

    welcomeScreen = Tk()
    welcomeScreen.geometry("550x375") 
    welcomeScreen.title("Account Login") 

    Button(text="Register", height="3", width="30", command = register).pack()
    Label(text="").pack()

def register():

     register_screen = Toplevel(welcome_screen) 
     register_screen.title("Register")
     register_screen.geometry("550x375")

     username = StringVar()
     password = StringVar()
     verifyPassword = StringVar()
     Label(register_screen, text="Please enter your new account details").pack()
```

**Full code**

```
from tkinter import *

def welcome_screen():
    global welcome_screen
    
    welcomeScreen = Tk()   # create a GUI window 
    welcomeScreen.geometry("550x375") # set the size of GUI window 
    welcomeScreen.title("Account Login") # set the title of GUI window

    # create a Welcome label
    Label(text="").pack()
    Label(text="Welcome", width="50", height="4", font=("Calibri", 17)).pack() 

    # create a login Button 
    Button(text="Login", height="3", width="30", command = login).pack() 
    Label(text="").pack() 

    # create a register button
    Button(text="Register", height="3", width="30", command = register).pack()
    Label(text="").pack()

    # create the exit button
    Button(text="Exit", height="2", width="10").pack()
    Label(text="").pack()
    Label(text="").pack()
    
    # start the GUI
    welcomeScreen.mainloop()


def register():
    global register
    global register_screen
    global username
    global password
    global verifyPassword
    global username_entry
    global password_entry
    global verifyPassword_entry
    
    register_screen = Toplevel(welcome_screen) 
    register_screen.title("Register")
    register_screen.geometry("550x375")

    username = StringVar()
    password = StringVar()
    verifyPassword = StringVar()
 
    # Set label for user's instruction
    Label(register_screen, text="").pack()
    Label(register_screen, text="").pack()
    Label(register_screen, text="Please enter your new account details",font = ("calibri", 17 )).pack()
    Label(register_screen, text="").pack()
    
    # Set username label
    username_lable = Label(register_screen, text="NEW USERNAME                          ",font=("calibri", 12))
    username_lable.pack()
 
    # Set username entry
    username_entry = Entry(register_screen, textvariable=username)
    username_entry.pack()
    
    # Set password label
    password_lable = Label(register_screen, text="NEW PASSWORD                         ",font=("calibri", 12))
    password_lable.pack()
    
    # Set password entry
    password_entry = Entry(register_screen, textvariable=password, show='*')
    password_entry.pack()
    
    # Set verify password label
    verifyPassword_lable = Label(register_screen, text="VERIFY PASSWORD                    ", font=("calibri", 12))
    verifyPassword_lable.pack()
    
    # Set verify password entry
    verifyPassword_entry = Entry(register_screen, textvariable=verifyPassword, show='*')
    verifyPassword_entry.pack()
    Label(register_screen, text="").pack()
    
    # Set register button
    Button(register_screen, text="Register", width=9, height=1, command = register_user).pack()
     

def register_user():
    
    # get username and password
    username_info = username.get()
    password_info = password.get()
    
    # hash the usernames and passwords before they are stored
    total = ""
    for char in range(len(username_info)):
        total = total + str(ord(username_info[char]))
    username_info = total

    total2 = ""
    for character in range(len(password_info)):
        total2 = total2 + str(ord(password_info[character]))
    password_info = total2
    
    # open the file of usernames and passwords in append mode
    with open("usernames and passwords","a") as file:
        file.write(username_info + "\n")
        file.write(password_info + "\n")

    # clear the entry boxes
    username_entry.delete(0, END)
    password_entry.delete(0, END)
    verifyPassword_entry.delete(0, END)
 
    # set a label for showing success information on screen
    Label(register_screen, text="Registration Success", fg="green", font=("calibri", 13)).pack()

 
def login():
    global login
    global username_verify
    global password_verify
    
    login_screen = Toplevel(welcome_screen)
    login_screen.title("Login")
    login_screen.geometry("550x375")
    Label(login_screen, text="").pack()
    Label(login_screen, text="").pack()

    # user instructions   
    Label(login_screen, text="Please enter details below to login",font = ("calibri", 17 )).pack()
    Label(login_screen, text="").pack()
 
    username_verify = ""
    password_verify = ""
 
    # username text entry
    Label(login_screen, text="USERNAME                                   ",font=("calibri", 12)).pack()
    username_login_entry = Entry(login_screen, textvariable=username_verify)
    username_login_entry.pack()

    # password text entry
    Label(login_screen, text="PASSWORD                                  ",font=("calibri", 12)).pack()
    password__login_entry = Entry(login_screen, textvariable=password_verify, show= '*')
    password__login_entry.pack()
    Label(login_screen, text="").pack()
    
    # login buttton
    Button(login_screen, text="Login", width=9, height=1, command=login_verification).pack()
    Label(login_screen, text="",font=("calibri", 3)).pack()

    # back button
    Button(login_screen, text="Back", width=9, height=1, command=welcome_screen).pack()
    
def login_verification():
    print("working...")

# call the welcome_screen function
welcome_screen()
```

Comment: I think that these are what you want: 1) change `global welcome_screen` to `global welcomeScreen` inside `welcome_screen()`; 2) change `Toplevel(welcome_screen)` to `Toplevel(welcomeScreen)` inside `register()`.

Comment: @acw1668 yeh thanks. Got too caught up in it and turns out it was very obvious

Comment: Please try not to post so much code. For example, we don't need all the widgets inside of the `Toplevel` if the question is about making the `Toplevel` appear.